# Ignore prometheus alertmanager inhibit rule

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have the following inhibit rule:

```
######## INHIBIT RULES ########
# Inhibit Rules: https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#inhibit_rule
inhibit_rules:
- source_match:
    severity: 'critical'
  target_match:
    severity: 'warning'
  # Apply inhibition if the alertname is the same on the same host.
  equal: ['alertname', 'instance', 'url']
###############################
```

This work 99% of the time as intended, however, some members would like their monitored devices to ignore the inhibit rule.

Is there a way I can add a label to those targets/rules so that:

```
if label ignore_inhibit is true

do not inhibit

else

proceed as planned
```

(I know how to add the label, I just don't know how to make alertmanagere ignore that label if it is possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following inhibit_rules:

```
inhibit_rules:
- source_match:
    severity: 'critical'
  target_matchers:
    matchers: [ severity = warning, ignore_inhibit != true ]
  equal: ['alertname', 'instance', 'url']
```